# search and login redirect to home page

Tags: solspace, htaccess, redirects, cache, static

All of a sudden  my search and member login forms always redirect to the home page rather than the redirect url or search results?  Any advice what's up?

```
{exp:member:login_form return="courses/online/55"}

<input name="username" class="form-login" title="Username" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" id="username" /></div>
<div id="login-box-name">Password:</div><div id="login-box-field"><input name="password" type="password" class="form-login" title="Password" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" id="password" /></div>
<br />
<span class="login-box-options"><input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"> Remember Me <a href="{path=login/forgot_password}" style="margin-left:30px;">Forgot password?</a></span>
<br />
<br />
<input type="image" name="submit" value="Submit" src="/images/login-btn.png"  style="margin-left:90px;" />
{/exp:member:login_form}
```

Content of the htaccess file.

```
##Solspace Static Page Caching: Site #1##
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

## RULE #1 - gzip

    ## Accepts GZ output
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip

    ## Ignore POST requests
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST

    ## Ignore EE Query requests
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(css|ACT)

    ## Override Cookie That Disables Caching
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(static_page_caching_override).*$

    ## Override Segment for ToolBar
    RewriteCond $1 !spc_override/*$

    ## Remove the index.php from the next conditional check, neutralize slashes
    RewriteCond $1 ^(index.php/)*(.*)(/*)$

    ## Cache File Exists?
    RewriteCond /home/hookingr/public_html/static_page_caching/1/$2/index.html.gz -f

    ## Redirect to Cache File
    RewriteRule ^(index.php/*)*(.*)(/*) /static_page_caching/1/$2/index.html.gz [L]

## RULE #2 - normal

    ## Ignore POST requests
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST

    ## Ignore EE Query requests
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(css|ACT)

    ## Override Cookie That Disables Caching
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(static_page_caching_override).*$

    ## Override Segment for ToolBar
    RewriteCond $1 !spc_override/*$

    ## Remove the index.php from the next conditional check, neutralize slashes
    RewriteCond $1 ^(index.php/)*(.*)(/*)$

    ## Cache File Exists?
    RewriteCond /home/hookingr/public_html/static_page_caching/1/$2/index.html -f

    ## Redirect to Cache File
    RewriteRule ^(index.php/*)*(.*)(/*) /static_page_caching/1/$2/index.html [L]

## RULE #3 - Remove SPC Override Segment from URI
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/spc_override$ /$1 [L]

</IfModule>
##END Solspace Static Page Caching: Site #1##


#allow from 192.185.1.20
#deny from all
RewriteEngine On 

#RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you have a 404 behaviour set for the site in the event you have strict URLs enabled? Push to the homepage is the default if you don't have it pointed elsewhere. Can you post a snippet of your member login form code, for example?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with my htaccess file.  I started to use the Static Page Cache module and as soon as I did this happened.  If I remove the module AND the contents of the htaccess file it works again.  I also remove index.php with my htaccess file.

Comment: If you leave the module in place but remove the content of your htaccess file (or just rename it) does it still work?  The hatches file is the same one you were using successfully with the site, removing index.php, before you installed the static caching module?

Comment: Correct, it is not the module itself, it is what the module is doing to the htaccess file.

Comment: Gotcha.  What does it change in your htaccess file (I've not used the add-on, but I see by the docs that it actually writes changes to it)?  There's an archived forum post (http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/15807/) that may be somewhat similar - I guess it depends on which method you re using for the index.php rewrite.

Comment: It adds everything in my original post above between 
##Solspace Static Page Caching: Site #1##
   AND   ##END Solspace Static Page Caching: Site #1##

Comment: I think this may be the answer:
{exp:static_page_caching:refresh_secure_hash}
http://www.solspace.com/docs/static_page_caching/refresh_secure_hash/

Comment: Yes, that appears to be it.